# Why this AVX2 slowdown with FMA x86 MS C Compiler?

Tags: c, x86, avx2, microbenchmark, fma

These are three classical starters for solving Kepler's equation and S3 provides an interesting example of deceptively short code fragments with odd timing behaviour. This problem concerns compiling them on the Microsoft C compiler x86 mode where anomalous behaviour is observed - namely that the AVX2 code at maximum optimisation for the notionally simpler code S3 takes much longer to execute than S9. No such problem with Intel (can't tell with GCC since x87 sin problem in Mingw prevents me from testing it).
All starters are functions of eccentricity 0 <= e <= 1 and Mean anomaly -pi <= M <= pi
These classical ones are by Gooding & Odel (1986)

```
double S1(double e, double M)
{ 
  if(M>0) return M + e; else return M - e;
  // simplest starter guaranteed to converge (eventually)
}
// convergence is not guaranteed with either S3 or S9 when e -> 1

double Gooding_S3(double e, double M)
{
  return M + e*sin(M)*(1+e*cos(M));  
// slow and fairly useless S9 is much more accurate!
}

double Gooding_S9(double e, double M)
{
 // originally written in their paper as sin(M)/sqrt(1-2*e*cos(M)+e*e)
 // it is one form of Halley's method but derived as the root of a
 // simple quadratic approximation for E-M. Rather good and fast e<0.7!
  double y;
  y = 1-e;
  if (M == 0.0) return M; // defend against divide by zero
  s = sin(M/2);
  return M+e*sin(M)/sqrt(y*y+4*e*s*s);  // more accurate form (very wrong when e -> 1)
}
```

A quick inspection of the number of operations and their nature suggests that they are in order of increasing execution time, but this isn't always the case! S9 is sometimes faster. Their operation counts subject to my counting errors are

1. S1 +
2. S3 ++ *** sincos
3. S9 -++ ***** / sin sin sqrt

Using standard _cdecl calling convention x86 code generation and MSC 2022 compiler today I get timings as follows for S3 and S9 (S1 is ~8 cycles from function call overheads). The 74 for AVX2 is **not** a typo! Problem goes away if code generation is x64.

| Starter | x87 | SSE2 | AVX | AVX2 | *_64 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S3 | 199 | 23 | 24 | 74 | 23 |
| S9 | 206 | 50 | 48 | 47 | 30 |

I have isolated the small code fragments that differ from S3 between AVX and AVX2 on x86 codegen but cannot see why one should be so much worse than the other. I'm also a bit amazed that S9 is quite so fast (and timing stable). x64 code is consistent and faster so I remain puzzled by it. I ran into it again through generating x87 trig code for the other question.

This is the much faster AVX code for S3 from sincos (no FMA)

```
call        ___libm_sse2_sincos_ (0BF7D50h)    
vshufpd     xmm1,xmm0,xmm0,1  
vmulsd      xmm1,xmm1,mmword ptr [e]  
vmulsd      xmm0,xmm0,mmword ptr [e]  
vaddsd      xmm1,xmm1,mmword ptr [__real@3ff0000000000000 (0BFBFB8h)]  
vmulsd      xmm0,xmm1,xmm0  
vaddsd      xmm0,xmm0,mmword ptr [M]  
vmovsd      qword ptr [esp],xmm0  
fld         qword ptr [esp]
```

And this is the slow S3 code from AVX2 using FMA apparently badly. I don't understand why.

```
 call        ___libm_sse2_sincos_ (0672600h)  
 vmovsd      xmm2,qword ptr [e]  
 vpermilpd   xmm1,xmm0,1  
 vfmadd213sd xmm2,xmm1,mmword ptr [__real@3ff0000000000000 (0676F50h)]  
 vmulsd      xmm0,xmm0,mmword ptr [e]  
 vfmadd213sd xmm0,xmm2,mmword ptr [M]  
 vmovsd      qword ptr [esp],xmm0  
 fld         qword ptr [esp] 2022
```

Why is the AVX2 code so much slower than AVX/SSE2 and why does it only happen for x86 code?

I'd be interested in suggestions for avoiding this sort of odd slowdown where shorter smarter code from an improved instruction set might result in worse performance. It seems to be much less of a problem with x64 code generation which might hint at it possibly being related to the old x86 linkage convention of returning FP results in ST(0).

It seems to be associated with transcendental library function calls but that may just be a sampling bias on my part.

Thanks for any enlightenment.

Comment: why you want 32 bit code?

Comment: @0 because x86 mode will allow me to use inline assembler _asm and 80bit x87 FP code in MSC.  x64 mode has neither :(  I don't often do it but sometimes it is useful.

Comment: Have a look at intel community page for similar issues.
https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-ISA-Extensions/Need-help-Why-my-avx-code-is-slower-than-SSE-code/m-p/1034874

Comment: That's sacrificing a *lot* just to get inline asm support in one compiler for an obsolete platform.  GCC and Clang have no problem with inline asm for any ISA, including x86-64.  (They're not compatible with MSVC inline asm syntax, though, and there are lots of reasons to avoid it (https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm) because it's non-trivial to get the constraints right even if you know exactly what you're doing.)  But with GCC and Clang, you don't need inline asm to get 80-bit x87, you can just use `long double`, unlike in MSVC where that's a 64-bit type.

Comment: @PeterCordes Agreed. But MS C++ is familiar even if a bit long in the tooth and non-standard. Intel remains my favourite compiler for heavy number crunching. I'm a newcomer to GCC and was unaware that it permitted inline assembler (I knew it had long double and supports quad precision which I have used (as does Salford Silverfrost Fortran). I'm still stuck on how to rebuild the MinGW libraries to get rid of their spurious x87 trig code. If all else fails I may have to bite the bullet and try installing WSL and Ubuntu for native Unix GCC. Unix is another of my blind spots.

Comment: *I'm still stuck on how to rebuild the MinGW libraries to get rid of their spurious x87 trig code* - Use 64-bit MinGW instead, unless you want to help future users who are stuck with 32-bit DLLs or something.  You said the only reason you wanted 32-bit in the first place was for MSVC inline asm, which GCC doesn't support at all.  64-bit builds of whatever libc MinGW uses shouldn't be using any x87 except in `long double` functions like `sinl`.

Comment: @PeterCordes That is what I'm doing. There is no difference! 64-bit MinGW GCC is internally calling _sinl_internal using x87 code for atan2, sin, cos, sincos, exp & log. I've just compiled it again and traced execution in GDB. -v gets Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32 version 13.1.0 (MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, I'm pretty sure that GCC works OK on native Unix from tests that others have done. This is a specific MinGW library problem that I'm seeing on 32 bit and 64 bit code. Benchmarks and error histograms of residual errors confirm it. tan(x) and atan(x) are the only ones using vector code.

Comment: Ok, that is weird and sounds like a bug for x86-64 MinGW.  I only have a GNU/Linux desktop, not a MinGW setup.

Comment: You can use regular non-inline assembly with MSVC x64 by the way (I use it a lot). That usually means that you have to write a bigger chunk of code in assembly, but MSVC inline assembly never really "connected" that well to the surrounding code anyway..